# Replace All Filepath Except Filename in Text file using Python

Tags: python, regex, linux, path

I have text file as follows. I want to remove all the filepath except leaving the filename. I need to read through the file and remove any file path. Its just to show the content of file as error to user. So displaying with the file path is an security issue.

**For eg:**

**From:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
 **/home/student/users/user_3/question_4/test.py** magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.**/home/student/users/user_3/question_4/test.py**  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

**To:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
 **test.py** magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.**test.py**  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

My Code:

```
import re

data = open('error.txt')
d = open('error1.txt', 'a+')

for line in data.readlines():
    if re.search(r'^[\S]+[_\d][\S]/', line):
        d.write(re.sub(r'^[\S]+[_\d][\S]/', '', line))
    elif re.search(r'^[\w]+[\s][\S][\S]+[_\d]\S/', line):
        d.write(re.sub(r'^[\w]+[\s][\S][\S]+[_\d]\S/', '', line))
    else:
        d.write(line)
d.close()
data.close()

print open('error1.txt').read()
```

Comment: Hi @khelwood. Its just a error text which i need to display as output to user. I want to remove those filepath from text file. Simple

Comment: @rkatkam No need for code its very simple question. I have a text file which is storing the errors of program. Now i want to remove any file path before displaying to user.

Comment: What is your **question** then?

Comment: No, that's not a question. Do you want us to write code for you? *What* do you want us to do?

Comment: I want a simple python function which should read a text file and remove any filepath from it and return the result. I have already written a function. but waiting for optimized solution.

Comment: If you want an optimized solution you should ask for a optimized solution instead of just a solution. Why don't you show the solution that you already have?

Comment: Really sorry @drscaon. I thought of getting better options than my solution

Comment: What about `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet http://stackoverflow.com/q/33981743/731947 ut enim ad minim veniam /home/student/users/user_3/question_4/test.py mollit anim id est laborum.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
import re
ere = re.compile(r'(^|[\"\s\W])\/[\w\.\/]+?\/([^\/"\s]+)([\"\s:]|$)', re.I)

def get_text_without_filepath(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return ere.sub("\g<1>\g<2>\g<3>", f.read())

get_text_without_filepath('my_file_with_error.txt')
```

Comment: This is really what i want. Thank you @baldr

Comment: Hi @baldr, Your code is working fine but have a small issue with one single testcase.

Comment: I hope your file names do not contain spaces in their names or quotes. Also bound char set can be extended - single quotes `'` and some other chars can be included..

Comment: The above is the only file content. Your code is not removing the above file path. Can u suggest a tweak

Comment: you're escaping too much, try to clean up the RegExp

Comment: I'm afraid that even not all cases included in this regexp, so it can grow up. Yes, readability sucks sometimes. How would you cleanup it?

Comment: Oh, you'd better to put somewhere all your input test files.. Ok, I have added line start-end bounds.

Comment: Its working fine now @baldr with all testcase :) Thank you